# Regular expression problem

Tags: asp.net, regex, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-express

I have the following regular expression in a asp.net email test box:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)\@((base\.co\.uk)|(base\.com)|(group\.com)|(arg\.co\.uk)|(arggroup\.com))
```

This regular expression only works for

```
xxx@base.co.uk
xxx@base.com
xxx@group.com
```

It's not working for:

```
xxx@arg.co.uk
xxx@arggroup.com
```

Please help me

Comment: @Jaison: Please post a minimal failing example that we can compile and run.

Answer (score 10):

This:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_-.]
```

contains a bogus range, underscore to dot.  Did you mean "underscore, dash or dot" like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]
```

?  Once I fix that, it works for me.

You should also use `\.` rather than `.` in the addresses - dot matches any character, so you'd match `baseXcom` with your pattern. (Note that you don't need a backslash for dots within `[]`s.)

The full corrected expression:

```
@"([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@((base\.co\.uk)|(base\.com)|(group\.com)|(arg\.co\.uk)|(arggroup\.com))"
```

(note that I'm using `@""` to avoid having to backslash my backslashes.)

Comment: according to http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.jsp this does match all your examples. Maybe your fault is somewhere else?

Answer (score 6):

Although I didn't get to the exact problem, You missed/overlooked an important point here. :-)

`'.'` is a wild card in regex, it matches anything.

to match '.' use

```
\.
```

lets try this

```
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-.]+)@(base\.co\.uk)|(base\.com)|(group\.com)|(arg\.co\.uk)|(arggroup\.com)
```

Comment: Can repost the correct expression from above ; i am confused now

Comment: @Rats: no need to escape a dot (.) in a character range ([]). A dot in a character ranges only matches a dot.

Comment: I am with Andrew - a dot has no special meaning inside a character group.

Answer (score 0):

Using the regular expression tester [here](http://yorktown.cbe.wwu.edu/sandvig/docs/RegExp.aspx) will probably help you.  However, as far as I can see, there's an error in the regular expression that should prevent it from working with **any** of the examples: the group should be:

```
[-a-zA-Z0-9_.]
```

With that fix, it works with all of your examples.  Having the `-` between the `_` and the `.` tries to construct a range, but the ASCII values are in the wrong order.

Also the dot used in the end part should be escaped as `base\.com` rather than `base.com`